# Что значит адрес вида 0x7fff и как его можно получить с помощью кода

Tags: python, python-2.x, ctypes

Вот пример кода где такой адрес используется:

```
import ctypes
a = 0x7fff 
print ctypes.cast(id(a), ctypes.py_object).value
```

Этот адрес может быть длинные либо короче. Мне нужно получить такой же адрес(или адреса) из процесса example.exe, также у меня есть PID этого процесса. Нигде просто не могу найти, что этот адрес значит и как его получить, особенно с помощью кода на Python.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы напечатаете 16-ричное представление того, что тут получается, то получите обратно это число.

```
print(hex(ctypes.cast(id(a), ctypes.py_object).value))
# 0x7fff
```

Адрес тут `id(a)`, а что в самой переменной `a` тут не важно, там может быть абсолютно любой объект питона. Например:

```
import ctypes
a = sum
print(ctypes.cast(id(a), ctypes.py_object).value)
# <built-in function sum>
```

В данном случае это ссылка на функцию. В общем, ваш код эквивалентен коду:

```
print(a)
```

Просто в нём показано, как получить что-то в питоне по адресу с помощью библиотеки `ctypes`.

Примечание: ваш код для питона 2.х, мой код для питона 3.х, но по сути разницы никакой нет кроме обращения с `print`.

Comment: А как я могу получить такой адрес процесса example.exe?

Comment: @Hojitakeish Так это вообще про другое. И насколько я понимаю в современных операционках нет возможности лазить в память других процессов. Там много ограничений, чтобы вирусы и прочее не шалили.